# SmartClient - opening record edit form

Tags: typescript, smartclient

There is a list and editing functionality.
[image]

When you double click on the row, edit form opens

[image]

I do not know exactly is this smartclient functionality or not, could not find in the examples https://smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/?autotest=showcase#main but this functionality uses smartclient.

There is private property

`readonly listGrid: isc.IListGrid<InvoiceDataSource.Record>`

so looks like SmartClient functionality.

I have found startEditing function

```
this.listGrid.startEditing(0);
```

but it just makes a row editable in the list, the values in columns become editable. It does not open the form.

I also tried

```
this.tabbedPage.edit(record);
```

but nothing happens. tabbedPage is defined this way:

```
readonly tabbedPage: crud.GuardedTabbedCrudPage<InvoiceDataSource.Record>
```

I see

```
this.tabbedPage.cancel();
```

works - it closes the edit page if it is opened. So something similar I expect with editing.

Or somehow I could trigger the even of mouse double click on the row - but how?

Tried callign editRecord but this nothing happens:

```
private async openCopiedInvoice(data) {
            
            this.tabbedPage.cancel();
            let record = await this.listGrid.fetchData({id: '7205'});
            
            data.form.editRecord(record);

        }
```

form looks like this:
[image]